# rlocus block diagram issue, k gain block before or after the summing junction for rlocus() command?

Tags: matlab, controls

[desired block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H06nA.png)
rlocus for the above transfer function should be pretty straight forward.

except on the help page of matlab the block diagrams look like this [matlab help block diagrams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydnoa.png)

what am I missing? is it the same?

```
%% assume plant G properly formulated
rlocus(G);
```

As far as I can tell, placement of gain block doesn't matter before or after the summing junction when considering the root locus, but I have no idea why that would be.